# How to make a view from pieces aligned to each other with different behavior android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, view, android-view

Let's say I have an animal face in pieces. I have an exterior, right ear, left ear, nose, mouse, eyes.
Each of this part is independent component, so even when all of it gathered into one, animation of nose is different from ears and doesn't happen at the same time.
So my question is how can I gather items together, so in future it will be a unit, but with separated behavior? Also I don't know how to place it, that ear is animating along the face, not overlaying and not with a hole between them.
Any ideas? Thanks.

*Edit*
This is an example of image I have (Original cannot share).

[image]

So on this image as on example nose, eyes, hair, eyebrows are separated elements. For example if I press on hair it will start one type of animation, if I drag nose (right or left) it will animate and change volume in video player.

My best idea for now is making each component as separated view and then in layout try to gather it together somehow, but I'm not sure it is correct and good idea at all.

Comment: Could you give any image as example? I would like to see shapes of those components and their arrangement. Are there fixed the same way in every animal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as you wrote, make **separated view** for each element with specific listener. Extending [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) should be sufficient solution - it gives you needed interfaces (e.g. [OnDragListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html) or [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)) and let you to keep clear your solution.

This seems to me like really pleasant task, which you can solve step by step, task by taks, component by component...

As to **container** for all animal's parts, it depends on requirements. If in all cases the eyes, ears, hairs etc. would be on the same or proportional location *for every animal* and *you put the animal more then once*, it would be worth to think about custom ViewGroup - probably [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

It is hard to give you more precise tips, because there will be a lot of minor and major requirements like I mentioned. For example, if size of eyes' images of two different animals aren't equal I would my components (rather than `View`) extend [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html), which gives us scaling features.

---

**Edit:** I' not sure it will be possible to accomplish it in this way, but I would try to do it like that:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <!-- LAYER 1: Face - background -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:gravity="center">
        <custom.path.FaceBaseComponent
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:src="@drawable/face_drawable"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- LAYER 1: Ears -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Left ear -->
        <custom.path.EarComponent
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="30"
                android:src="@drawable/left_ear"/>

        <!-- Filler -->
        <View 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="40"/>

        <!-- Right ear -->
        <custom.path.EarComponent
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="30"
                android:src="@drawable/right_ear"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This help you to save proportions between each element. Keep trying to merge as many "layers" as you can (maybe you can put ears and eyes inside single `LinearLayout`?).

Comment: and for aligning inside `RelativeLayout` you think it will shapes automatically with rules for layout? all elements have transparent background, I haven't try, but just suspect that it will handle transparent part as part of image,so will be a hole between them..

Comment: That's why I asked an example (and preferably two of them) :) If I would know the rules - what is resizing, what has always the same location etc., I would be able to propose anything.

Comment: there is everything separated. I'm not sure but maybe it would be possible to put everything one on one in a line, so I'll set `match_parent` for each view, then nose will overlay exterior etc. The idea seems full, so need to process it, question seems dead :) Anyways thank for your answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: So I added my idea, I hope it at least inspire you somehow :) Good luck!